# Guardar número sin formato

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quiero que al digitar un número en el `input` me coloque separadores de miles, pero al guardar ese mismo número en la base de datos no me tome el número formateado. Hasta el momento tengo el siguiente código, formatea correctamente, pero no sé cómo eliminar ese formato al momento de guardar.

**PHP**

```
INSERT INTO combustible (id, VALOR) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['VALOR'], "text"));
```

**HTML + JS**

```js
function format(input) {
  var num = input.value.replace(/\./g, '');
  if (!isNaN(num)) {
    num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g, '$1.');
    num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/, '');
    input.value = num;
  } else {
    alert('Solo se permiten numeros');
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g, '');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="VALOR" id="VALOR" onkeyup="format(this)" maxlength="7" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que el formato que haces es poner un . para el separador de miles. Entonces en PHP, en lugar de pasar directamente la variable `$_POST['VALOR']` a la consulta, puedes procesarla antes para quitar ese formato. Por ejemplo, usa [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) para quitar el punto del número.

Además de eso, y para asegurarnos de que el usuario no ha hecho algún cambio más que pueda crear problemas (siempre que valides en JS deberías hacer una validación similar en el lado del servidor por seguridad), podrías hacer un [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php) para asegurarte de que el valor es un número.

Algo como esto:

```
// leemos el valor de $_POST['VALOR'] y le quitamos los .
$valor = intval(str_replace(".", "", $_POST['VALOR']));

//...

INSERT INTO combustible (id, VALOR) VALUES (%s, %s)",
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"),
               GetSQLValueString($valor, "text"));
```